# Neo4j missing node from collect function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Please consider this example: there are three Groups and four Persons:

```
CREATE (group1:Group {
  name: 'Group 1'
})
CREATE (group2:Group {
  name: 'Group 2'
})
CREATE (group3:Group {
  name: 'Group 3'
})
CREATE (personA:Person {name: 'Anna'})
CREATE (personB:Person {name: 'Bob'})
CREATE (personC:Person {name: 'Carla'})
CREATE (personD:Person {name: 'Denis'})
CREATE
  (personA)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(group1),
  (personB)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(group1),
  (personB)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(group2),
  (personC)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(group2),
  (personC)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(group3),
  (personD)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(group3)
```

Anna and Bob belong to Group 1, Bob and Carla are members of Group 2, and Carla and Denis are in Group 3. 
A simple cypher query will show this relation:

```
MATCH (g:Group)<-[:IS_PART_OF]-(m:Person)
RETURN g, collect(DISTINCT m)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| g                       | collect(DISTINCT m)                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[2]{name:"Group 3"} | [Node[6]{name:"Denis"},Node[5]{name:"Carla"}] |
| Node[1]{name:"Group 2"} | [Node[5]{name:"Carla"},Node[4]{name:"Bob"}]   |
| Node[0]{name:"Group 1"} | [Node[4]{name:"Bob"},Node[3]{name:"Anna"}]    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows
```

Now, I want to show all groups to which Anna and Bob belong, with all the members that are in those groups, **including** Anna and Bob.

My query is following:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(g:Group)<-[:IS_PART_OF]-(m:Person)
WHERE p.name IN ['Anna', 'Bob']
RETURN g, collect(DISTINCT m)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| g                       | collect(DISTINCT m)                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"Group 2"} | [Node[5]{name:"Carla"}]                    |
| Node[0]{name:"Group 1"} | [Node[4]{name:"Bob"},Node[3]{name:"Anna"}] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows
```

The result is not what I expected to get.

Why Bob is not shown, as a member of Group 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node on the left side of the pattern will not be repeated on the right side if the relationship of the pattern matches the left and right sides.

Try this query:

```
// Find group
MATCH (p:Person)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(g:Group) WHERE p.name IN ['Anna', 'Bob']
// Get all person from group
WITH g 
  MATCH (g)<-[:IS_PART_OF]-(m:Person)
RETURN g, COLLECT(distinct m)
```

For a better understanding see the result of this query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(g:Group)<-[:IS_PART_OF]-(m:Person)
WHERE p.name IN ['Anna', 'Bob']
RETURN g, p, m

╒═══════════════╤════════════╤═════════════╕
│g              │p           │m            │
╞═══════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│{name: Group 1}│{name: Anna}│{name: Bob}  │
├───────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┤
│{name: Group 2}│{name: Bob} │{name: Carla}│
├───────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┤
│{name: Group 1}│{name: Bob} │{name: Anna} │
└───────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
```

When you apply `g, collect(distinct m)` for `group 1` you collect `Bob` and `Anna` and for `group 2` you collect `Carla`.

Comment: Great explanation!